# Should home page include both a "Search" and a "View All" button?

Tags: search, accessibility, homepage

Near the top of our home page, we have a search bar. Next to the search bar is a `VIEW ALL` button:

[image: search bar]

The `VIEW ALL` button takes the user to the same place that the `SEARCH` button would go if no text was entered. (There is also a menu item in the main navigation which also takes the user to a list page.)

We are split on whether or not to keep the `VIEW ALL` button.

**ARGUMENTS FOR KEEPING IT:** It's not clear that the `SEARCH` button will take the user to a list of everything. I.E., the user will think "I don't want to search, I just want to view browse them all".

**ARGUMENTS FOR REMOVING IT:** It's redundant functionality.

So, from a UX perspective, is it better to have both buttons, or just the one?

** I know I'm not providing *full* context, and I'd love to provide a link to the site or an image to the entire homepage, but that's not possible.

Comment: What does your user testing results suggest?

Comment: "View all" what? News, Users, Articles, Address,... This concept is too broad to be placed in such a generic place. You should place it in specific page.

Comment: How many results are there if no search term is entered? And is it relevant/useful to have a list of it all?

Comment: **If** the website is specific enough that @MaisaBarros's well-made point doesn't apply, and _if_ there's no issues over space for including it, then I'd say it could be useful: some people won't associate "searching for an empty string" with "viewing everything" (justifiably, since some search functions won't let you do this).

Comment: Clicking the Search button with no text in the field isn't something people will think to do. So I wouldn't say that the View All is redundant. Keep it.

Comment: @MaisaBarros -- normally that would be true, but what TripeHound hinted at is our case: we list _only_ one thing (it's niche)

Answer (score 1):

It is better to remove that VIEW ALL button and go with the only search button.
you also have alternatives like.

1. if possible provide filters for the remaining list.
   like the one google uses.[image]
2. You can show the basic search list at the first time and include show more button at the bottom of the list.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What about alternating button text: "View All" if search box is empty and "Search" when you enter search text?

That keeps your design and makes it clear to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You should show search button prominently instead of View all too. Add view all button or tag in the list page where you are redirecting the user after clicking the search button.

You can give advance search kind of thing in which user can select different parameters to search. So this would be easy for the user to come to know that what kind of data they will have.

Another solution is put placeholder Text in search bar like "Search for username or location...etc." It is the name of parameters for that you are allowing to search.

As per the UX perspective, you should not mention view all button.

If you want to give view all feature then show all the list at the time of clicking on search button only i.e. without entering any search keywords.

Here I have attached some images for the reference that you can use to give view all functionality.

In short, don't show view all button prominently.
[enter link description here](http://www.uiparade.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/search-bar-drop-down-free-psd.jpg)